# Duplicate class in two modules in an application - which will be referred to by an instantiating class?

Tags: java, classloader, ear, oc4j

There is an EAR(`myApp.ear`) of a web application in which there are two modules - a web module (`myWeb.war`) and an EJB module (`myModel.jar`). Now there is a class `myDuplicate.class` which is present in both the modules in the same package `myPackage`. The implementation of the class is different in both modules.

If a class in the web module creates an object of the class `myDuplicate` then the object will be of from the one in `myWeb` or the one in `myModel`?

Does this depend on classloading mechanisam of the server? If yes, is there a parameter in `OC4J` server configuration to control this classloading? If no, then what controls it?

---

The above may have seemed too generic but that it is a practical problem that I am facing. In different environments different classes are being loaded but I am unable to find out what is controlling it. I tried searching and came to classloaders which might be the answer. But even after that I was unable to find how to control it to behave in a consistent manner in both environments.

If anything is not clear please share what is not and I will try to clarify.

Comment: It would only be duplicate if the FQN's were equal. If they are, the JVM will load the first one encountered by the class loader, which I think means it depends on the specifics behind how the classloader you're using finds them on disk. This link might shed some light on how the classloader evaluates entities on the class path (assuming youre using the default classloader): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html

Comment: @MarkW The package and class name is same. So yeah, FQN is same. I am not using classloaders, the app server is but I don't know how to control it. BTW is there anything besides class loading which can affect the choice of the class?

Comment: Not that im aware of, but what you could test, and im pretty sure will work, is to make sure that the dependencies which contain the duplicate class appear in the same order on the ClassPath JVM arg for your apps. I dont know how that works with ear files, but from my understanding, if your classpath's are equal (meaning the order of elements in it), you should load the same classes in the same way across different apps, and in addition, be able to control which gets used by putting it first in the list relative to its duplicate.

Comment: have a look on [Installing and Publishing a Shared Library in OC4J](http://otndnld.oracle.co.jp/document/products/as10g/101300/B25221_03/web.1013/b14433/classload.htm#CIHDGJGD)

Comment: @s106mo I don't understand how that is relevant.

Answer (score 4):

There are very clear rules on class visibility in Java EE compliant application servers.

In summary (and in the absence of any manifest Class-Path entries, external libraries or RAR files), modules in an EAR file are  defined as follows:

- Each web module consists of the content of WEB-INF/classes plus all jars within the WEB-INF/lib directory
- Each ejb module is standalone
- The contents of the EAR/lib directory are considered to be a single module for class visibility.

Given the above:

- web modules are isolated and cannot see each other's classes, but they can see EAR/lib classes. They can often see ejb modules too, but this not a requirement. A compliant application would use a manifest Class-Path entry to resolve this.
- ejb modules can see their own specified client jar classes and EAR/lib classes. They can often see other ejb modules too, but this not a requirement. A compliant application would use a manifest Class-Path entry to resolve this.
- jars in the EAR/lib directory can only see each other's classes

So, hopefully that gives you a clear idea of class visibility between the different components. However, you still need a clear picture of class loading order:

- a web module's own classes will *always* be used before looking in the other class loaders.
- "parent first" class loading applies everywhere else.

In your particular case, `myDuplicate` from `myWeb` would be created. You should be fine provided you don't attempt to pass an instance of `myDuplicate` up into `myModel`. This will likely result in class loading issues.

I see this kind of problem often in the wild when developers bundle log4j (or some other logging library) in both their EAR files and their web modules, resulting in lots of class loading problems.

See `§EE.8.2 Library Support` of `Java™ Platform, Enterprise Edition (Java EE) Specification, v6`  for more of the gory details.

Comment: This makes things a lot clear. But there is still one observation which this explanation does not explain. The web application that I am talking about in question is a `struts-1` application. One `ActionForm` class was present in both the web as well as EJB module. I know that is a problem in the EAR but that is how it is. In one server the AF was being loaded from JAR, in other from WAR. I verified it through logging. How does that happen? Also you write `compliant application`. I was under the impression that it is the server which needed to be complaint. Can you explain?

Comment: In the context of `compliant application` (vs `compliant application server`), it is your application that must provide [manifest class path entries](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) where required

Comment: Anything regarding the duplicate `ActionForm` behaviour that I mentioned for OC4J server?

Comment: A quick look at [Specifying search-local-classes-first at Deployment Time](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13979_01/classload.htm#CIHJFCCE) suggests that your two servers might have different deployment plans

Comment: That is for libraries. Right? Not for the application itself. `which causes the class loader to find and load any libraries packaged in the WAR and to use these libraries rather than the corresponding libraries packaged with OC4J`. This says that the parameter is for disambiguation between OC4J and web application libraries, not between two modules of the same application.

Comment: No. There is web-app level config that specifies whether classes are loaded from the web-app first, or the parent first. This can be specified at deployment time.

Comment: Last question. If it is web-app level config for all classes inside the modules then why does the whole link https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13979_01/classload.htm#CIHJFCCE refers to `shared libraries`. Libraries mean `jar` files specified in MANIFEST or applib folder or in lib folder. Part of modules are not considered as libraries. Right?

Answer (score 0):

To solve duplicate definitions on oracle OC4J you can add these configs on orion-application.xml or orion-web.xml.

1) WEB-INF/orion-web.xml config: Adding expected jars on web-inf/lib or pom.xml (not provided):

```
<orion-web-app ...>
  <web-app-class-loader search-local-classes-first="true" />
</orion-web-app>
```

2) META-INF/orion-application.xml: With duplicated lib name (showed on log message), remove your link config:

```
<orion-application ...>
  <imported-shared-libraries>
    <remove-inherited name="name.of.your.lib"/>
  </imported-shared-libraries>
</orion-application>
```

3) Pack these files/modifications on your .war file and deploy it on oc4j.